# Total convergence of a particular series of functions

Tags: calculus

I have to solve the following exercise:

In which of the following intervals the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n x^n \ln(x)$ is totally convergent?

$[0,1];$

$[a,1];$ for all $0<a<1$

$[0,a]$  for all $0<a<1$

I think the second is the only correct. But if I calculate $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \sup |x^n \ln(x)|$, I obtain 
$$
\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{en},
$$
so I don't have any information concerning the total convergence of this series.

Comment: What does "total convergence" mean? Perhaps "absolute" or "uniform" or something like that?

Comment: Total convergence means that there exists a convergent numeric sequence $M_n$ such that $|f_n(x)| \le M_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N} $. I'm sorry, but in italian we express this concept with the term "convergenza totale".

Comment: "...for all $\;n\;$ **and for all** $\;x\;$", right? This condition you mention assures the series converges uniformly: it is simply Weierstrass M-test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The supremum of $|x^n\ln x|$ is attained at $x=e^{-1/n}$, which converges to $1$ as $n\to\infty$. In an interval $[0,a]$ with $0<a<1$, $|x^n\ln x|$ will be increasing for $n<1/\ln(1/a)=N_a$. The for all $n\ge N_a$
$$
\sup_{0\le x\le a}|x^n\ln x|=a^n|\ln a|.
$$
Since $0<a<1$, $\sum a^n|\ln a|<\infty$.

By the way, this type of convergence is sometimes called *normal convergence*. The sequence does not converge normally on any interal that contains $1$.